# Please make the "This post has been edited while you were editing" notifier link back to the question

Tags: feature-request, edits

If I am in the middle of a substantial edit of a new question, the odds are that it will be edited by other users (perhaps several of them) before I can finish.

This triggers the notifier:

> Be advised: this post has been edited 2 times by other users while you were editing

But since the "back to question" link was removed some time ago, it's hard to find the question in its current form to see which of my changes are still valid. I have to open the questions list in a new tab, sort by newest, and then scroll around hoping that the title hasn't changed so much as to be unrecognizable. So I end up crossing my fingers and clicking the save button anyway.

Can we have a link in the notifier, even if nowhere else?

<sub>I know there have been several related requests, but I don't *think* this is an exact duplicate.</sub>

Comment: I'm glad to hear the "back to question" link was _removed_; I thought I was just going insane and _imagined_ that it used to be far easier to find the question after editing collisions.