# When someone edits what you're editing, make a link back to the question

Tags: feature-request, edits, user-interface

Recently I was editing a question and got a notification that someone else already edited it. Ok, that's neat. So I wanted to see what they edited so I didn't mess their edit up. I looked up and down on the page for a link back to the question, but I couldn't find one. I ended up having to middle click(open new tab) the stackoverflow logo and then search for the question I was editing. (note: I had worked about 3 minutes on editing the question so I didn't want to lose my changes)

Anyway, I think this is insane and way too difficult for what I'm trying to do. Why not make the edit notification at least be a clickable link back to the question, or better yet add a "return to question" link somewhere on the edit page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please make the "This post has been edited while you were editing" notifier link back to the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80383/please-make-the-this-post-has-been-edited-while-you-were-editing-notifier-link)